<ion-content> causing modal height to collapse to 0
(Solved, see comments)
I have a component that serves as a modal. When I wrap the HTML template inside an ion-content tag, the modal's height collapses to 0.
The code setup I'm going to share is the only content from the ionic
framework in the project
Let me go through the code setup
TestPage component Ts:
    export class TestPageComponent { 
    constructor(
      private modalController: ModalController
    ) { }
    }

TestPage component Html:
    <ion-content>
      <h1>TESTING</h1>
      <h1>TESTING</h1>
      <h1>TESTING</h1>
      <h1>TESTING</h1>
    </ion-content>

I have a service that handles the initiation of the TestPage modal using ModalController, as so:
BottomsheetHelper Service:
export class BottomsheetHelperService {

  constructor(
    private modalController: ModalController
  ) { }

  async openTestPage(): Promise<void> {

    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: TestPageComponent,
      mode: 'ios',
      handle: true,
      backdropDismiss: false,
      breakpoints: [0, 1],
      initialBreakpoint: 1,
      canDismiss: true,
      focusTrap: false,
    });

    await modal.present();
  }
}

Then in a parent view I call this:
    this.bottomSheetHelperService.openTestPage();

With the ion-content tags present, when triggering the modal, the backdrop appears, but the content and modal itself are not visible.
But if I remove the ion-content tags like this:
    <!-- Commenting out ion-content -->
    <h1>TESTING</h1>
    <h1>TESTING</h1>
    <h1>TESTING</h1>
    <h1>TESTING</h1>
    <!-- Commenting out ion-content -->

The modal displays correctly:

If I explicitly define a height using viewport units to the ion-content tag, the content appears as expected:
    <ion-content style="height: 60vh">
      <h1>TESTING</h1>
      <h1>TESTING</h1>
      <h1>TESTING</h1>
      <h1>TESTING</h1>
    </ion-content>

Result:

What I have tried:

Initially, adding viewport units to ion-content resolved the issue, but this approach is not suitable since the modal should dynamically adjust its height to fit the content rather than forcing a viewport height.

Checked for any conflicting CSS that might be causing the collapse of ion-content, but there is nothing stated anywhere globally.

Setting different height properties:


  ion-content {
    height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    --height: 100%;
    --height: auto;
  }

From what I understand, the Ionic framework is designed to handle ion-content height automatically, without the need for manual adjustments or "hacks". But then why does the content collapse in this case, and the only way to display the content is by explicitly setting a viewport height.
I hope anyone can come with some insight to this problem.
CodeSanbox
You'll have to run 'npm start' and not 'ng serve' in the terminal
Thanks

What ionic/angular version are you on? Can you provide a reproducible example with stack blitz?

@StackoverBlows Ionic 8.2.6, I have set up a CodeSandbox project. Stackblitz isn't working properly when introducing Ionic for some reason. I have included a hyperlink to the topic in the end

why are you using modalController? using inline modal is the recomanded way now. please try inline modals.

@NajamUsSaqib -- modal controllers are still being used and will never go away. its a way to do it programatically.  Most things you can do with modalController, you cannot do with inline modals. The inline modals are just another way to do "modals".

@Gent -- there are all types of errors in that thing: Cannot find module '@ionic/angular' or its corresponding type declarations. here is a base ionic 7 stackblitz that you can fork off of: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ywh4p1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

@StackoverBlows I'm not quiet sure what you mean and why you are getting those error, you can look for yourself in the app.module. Everything is set up correctly. Just run 'npm start' in the terminal and you are good to go.

@NajamUsSaqib My project is built using Angular Material's MatBottomSheet. Now that I’m looking into using the Ionic Framework, it seems like that the best fit to switch to Ion Modals is by using the Modal Controller. Switching to inline modals would involve a lot more work, and the Modal Controller can handle this just fine.
From what I’ve read, it doesn’t seem like inline modals are the only recommended way to do it. Check out the Modal Controller here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal#controller-modals

@StackoverBlows I think I found the "Solution", or actually I found out that it actually isn't intended to use ion-content unless the height of the modal is known beforehand:
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/27846#issuecomment-1650405207
